# jQuery + .before() + var = not working?

Tags: jquery

I have no idea what's going on. The links just won't show up:

```
var se_buttons = {
    'b': {
        'tag' : 'b'
    },
    'i': {
        'tag' : 'i'
    },
    'url': {
        'tag' : 'url'
    },
    'size': {
        'tag' : 'size'
    },
    'spoiler': {
        'tag' : 'spoiler'
    },
    'align': {
        'tag' : 'align'
    }
};

function se_make_button(button, text) {
    return '<a href="#" class="button se_button se_button_'+button+'">'+text+'</a>';
}

function se_create ( obj, toolbar ) {
    var se_toolbar = '';
    for (var button in se_buttons) {
        se_toolbar = se_toolbar + se_make_button(se_buttons[button].tag, se_buttons[button].tag);
    }
    $(obj).before(se_toolbar);
}
```

`toolbar` is a simple object with properties. When alerting out each thing individually, they all work and all the info shows correctly. When doing the same `.before()` command from the console, it works too. But in the code -- it doesn't! What can I do further? :/
I spent about 2 hours trying to work this around, but I can't figure what's going on >< I also tried `.replaceWith()` or other similar but it just won't work from the inside code. Explicitly running the code manually from the console works though D:

---

**Edit:** The weird thing is that if I put an alert with the exact variable inside the `before()` part, the string is fine. If I manipulate `$(obj)` in any other way, it works. The conjunction of the variables and the object doesn't wanna fiddle.

Comment: Make a testcase please. We can't see `se_buttons`, or your invocation of `se_create`.

Comment: Added se_buttons -- it's a simple object, I know it appears I built it uselessly but I plan to add more properties, this is a placeholder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have no idea what happened, but it just works now. I think I made it explicitly call on document ready rather than just using it as an out of the blue call.

Answer (score 0):

I took your code as is, and managed to run it fine. In IE 7,8,9 and FF.
You can take a look here. 
http://jsfiddle.net/87UUD/7/

What does your html look like? How do you call the se_create method?

Comment: This should have been a comment.